# iOS Catalyst Cocoapod framework error - signing requires a development team

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, mac-catalyst

I'm updating my iOS app to also work on Mac. After selecting the Mac checkbox, I am getting the error in the screenshot below when trying to build for Mac. It's telling me I need to select a development team for this Cocoapod framework. However, I can build to an iPhone or iPad without selecting a development team.

I tried selecting a development team which made the error go away but when I uploaded the app binary to Apple, it was rejected with the error: ITMS-90284: Invalid Code Signing - The executable 'Timestamp.app/Contents/Frameworks/BSImagePicker.framework/Versions/A/Resources/BSImagePicker.bundle' must be signed with the certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile.

I am thinking I'm getting this error from Apple because I selected a development team for this Cocoapod framework.

Any suggestion on how to handle this error for a Catalyst app?

[image: Mac Build Error]

Comment: Do you have a paid Apple developer account?

Comment: @Andrew yes, and multiple apps already on the App Store for iOS.

Comment: I'm also seeing this same problem. Related to this CocoaPods issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8891

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue setting the `development team` to each `pod` during `pod install` like this issue from `CocoaPods` repo describes: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8891#issuecomment-546636698

You need to add the following at the end of your `Podfile`:

```rb
def fix_config(config)
  if config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'].nil?
    config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'] = '<YOUR TEAM ID HERE>'
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        fix_config(config)
    end
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        fix_config(config)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you need to do a `pod install` in order for it to work.

You can find your `team id` here: https://developer.apple.com/account/#!/membership

### 2022 fall Apple Developer site

[image]

### old Apple Developer site

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have this issue with MessageKitAssets, this works for me:

Select MessageKitAssets from pods targets,

Select a team manually, and set signing certificate 'sign to run locally' (for platform macOS)
Use iOS bundle id, provision profile not required.

Comment: Still an issue as of January 2021; selecting my own "team" and "sign to Run Locally" also was the missing piece for me. After doing this I was able to upload my Mac Catalyst binary and it was processed without issue.

Comment: @lukemmtt did you find a solution?

Comment: @VladKhambir No, nothing more than the workaround presented here by Sam Xu. The workaround is tedious because it needs to be performed on 5 different frameworks every time I build for Mac Catalyst, but it gets the job done and my app passed the App Store review with this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
post_install do |installer|

1. Add the below code at the end of POD file.
2. Install the pod again
3. Run the app

installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score -5):

Add this to the top of your podfile:

`source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`